# Theme removed "Edit Post" link on the front end. I wish it back

Tags: posts

I see that theme authors are removing the front-end 'Edit Post' links these days.

I've installed WP User Front End plugin and i'd like to be able to allow the Post Authors to have an 'Edit Post' link right on the page or in the content (in a Post Grid) like it used to be.

ah, them were the days... just kidding...

anyway, can someone kindly help me with a way to get that back for me for any author, not just Admin, Editor, etc...? (the Authors have permissions set)

Answer (score 1):

ok, in a straight WP theme file (single.php) i simply found

```
                    the_content();
```

and placed this after it since i wasn't worried about the placement of the link too much:

```
                    edit_post_link( $link, $before, $after, get_the_ID() );
```

worked great.

Comment: This answer is basically correct. I'm not familiar with your front-end plugin (which is off-topic here) but it may be that it has removed or hidden your Edit Post link. Or you could be correct that the theme has removed it. You'd need to check with the respective plug-in and theme developers to know.

Comment: yep, in fact, that's what i meant by "i see that some authors are..." - sorry. I came across a forum where a couple of theme authors did confess to removing the function for personal reasons. think it had something to do with an childhood incident with ... just kidding. they said that they felt it was unnecessary or obsolete or something. not surprised, tho. the whole theme is garbage (i didn't choose it...)